# How can I crop images according to the window size?

Tags: kivy, kivy-language

In the case that an image isn't the size of the window, would it be possible to have the image expand so it covers the entire window and crop itself to fit rather than losing its proportions?

Comment: Do the `allow_stretch` and `keep_ratio` properties of the `Image`not suffice? I know they don't do cropping, but they do stretch the image to fit.

Comment: Hi @JohnAnderson, those two properties do in fact work with the exception of the cropping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really want to stretch and crop an `Image`, you can use the `StencilView` to do the cropping. Here is a possible implementation:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.uix.stencilview import StencilView

class MyStencilView(FloatLayout, StencilView):
    def on_size(self, *args):
        self.children[0].adjust_image_size(self)

class MyImage(Image):
    def adjust_image_size(self, stencil):
        stencil_ratio = stencil.width / float(stencil.height)
        if self.image_ratio > stencil_ratio:
            self.width = stencil.height * self.image_ratio
            self.height = stencil.height
        else:
            self.width = stencil.width
            self.height = stencil.width / self.image_ratio

theRoot = Builder.load_string('''
FloatLayout:
    MyStencilView:
        MyImage:
            size_hint: None, None
            pos_hint: {'center_x':0.5, 'center_y':0.5}
            keep_ratio: True
            allow_stretch: True
            source: '/path/to/some/image'
''')

class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return theRoot

TestApp().run()
```

The idea is that the `MyImage` widget gets its size adjusted as needed to allow the `MyStencilView` to do the cropping. The `FloatLayout` base of `MyStencilView` allows the use of `pos_hint`, which, in this case, insures that the cropping is centered on the image.